Three datacenters and mongoDB replica set with a requirement of local availability to read
We have three datacenters which are connected via private network (not connected to Internet). We use MongoDB to store data. One datacenter is a backup of another and for this we configured a replica set. All writings are done in a specific datacenter, say DC1.
DC1 (primary) <-- Here is running service which writes data into DB
DC2 (secondary) <-- only reads here
DC3 (secondary) <-- only reads here

Now consider a case when the connection to one of the datacenters fails, for example DC2 and it becomes isolated:
Network 1:
DC1 (primary) <-- Here is running service which writes data into DB
DC3 (secondary) <-- only reads here

Network 2:
DC2 (secondary) <-- only reads here


We do not have majority (50%+1 nodes) on its side, but we still need it to function for reads only (mostly by services running on the same node as the secondary) until the network is restored. This fail-tolerance should be done automatically. The fact there is no majority of secondaries available makes it unable to become primary (which is correct), but we need to keep using it for read only operations.
I know there are special secondaries like arbiter that can be added but no amount of them will solve the problem because we need the same behavior in case of network failure for DC3 as well.
We are struggling to find a compatible configuration of replica set for our case. Looks like the whole replica set as provided by MongoDB doesn't fit our requirement. Maybe there is another mechanism that could be applied here?
Will really appreciate any help. If I missed some data you need to answer this question, please write in the comments.
MongoDB: 7.0

This is more of a question for DBA stack exchange, but I'm confused by the premise of the question altogether. "but we need to keep using it for read only operations" - it is available for reads when it is on SECONDARY state, just be sure to use an eligible read preference, perhaps primaryPreferred: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-primaryPreferred

@user20042973 Thank you for your comment. If I duplicate my question on DBA stack exchange will it violate rules?

@user20042973 and regarding the secondary state, when DC2 becomes isolated we are unable to connect to it. Are you sure it should work? Maybe we are doing something wrong with configuration

If DC2 gets isolated then the majority (DC1 and DC3) is still available. Your assumption is wrong. If you connect properly,  then then client will automatically read from DC1 or DC3 depending on readPreference settings.

Maybe read also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658590/mongoclient-to-connect-to-multiple-hosts-to-handle-failover/69666511#69666511

How do you connect to the MongoDB?

@WernfriedDomscheit Thank you for commenting. The problem is on the side of isolated DC2. We need processes that run on it to have a read access to the data while it is disconnected from the rest of data centers. This is not something you think of in a standard scenario.

It is the standard scenario. Usually a datacenter does not power off. Most common problem is when it gets disconnected from then rest of the network while the DC itself remains running. Again, how do you connect and what is your problem? It should simply work with standard setup, that's the main purpose of a Replica Set.

You situation really looks like the standard setup for a Replica Set.
Just give a higher priority on DC1 than the other have, that's it.
members: [
  {_id: 0, host: 'host1.dc1:27017', priority: 10},      
  {_id: 1, host: 'host1.dc2:27017', priority: 1},
  {_id: 2, host: 'host1.dc3:27017', priority: 1}
]

In case DC2 is not reachable by the other members, then 2 out of 3 are still reachable, i.e. DC1 remains as primary and your entire database is fully available. When you connect to DC 2 directly, then you can still read from it.
Note, in order to elect a primary the majority of all members must be available - or more precisely the majority of all voting members.
Some more information:

The majority on a side does not matter. Relevant is the number of available and reachable members in entire Replica Set. No matter if they run in different datacenter or even if they run all on a single machine (which does not make much sense for production database).
You cannot control by Replica Set configuration from where the client reads the data. You define this only on the client side.
By default, you cannot define from which secondary the client reads the data - unless you work with Replica Set Tag Sets but for only three members it does not make much sense.


I don't think this answer addresses OP's actual concern which I took to be "How do I read from the SECONDARY in DC2 when it cannot communicate with the rest of the replica set?".

@user20042973 exactly!

Please see my update
